# Load data from JSON file to a table

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have a Core Data model called 'List' with 4 attributes and wanted to populate the data from the JSON file to an array of type 'List'

when I run the app, it gives me the error 'fatal error: Array index out of range'

```
var loadNames = [List]()

var context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext!
var frc: NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController()
func getFetchedResultsController() -> NSFetchedResultsController {
    frc = NSFetchedResultsController(
        fetchRequest: listFetchRequest(),
        managedObjectContext: context,
        sectionNameKeyPath: "done",
        cacheName: nil)
    return frc
}
func listFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "List")
    let doneSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "done", ascending: false)
    let nameSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "firstName", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [doneSortDescriptor, nameSortDescriptor]
    return fetchRequest
}
func isFrequent(item: List) -> Bool {
    return item.frequent == true
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    var readError:NSError?
    let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("NameList", ofType:"json")
    let data = NSData(contentsOfFile:filePath!, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingUncached, error:&readError)
    var jData = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers, error: &readError) as! NSArray

    for i in 0..<jData.count {
        if let jfName = jData[i]["firstName"] as? String {
            if let jlName = jData[i]["lastName"] as? String {
                if let jDone = jData[i]["done"] as? NSNumber {
                    if let jFrequent = jData[i]["frequent"] as? NSNumber {

                        loadNames[i].firstName = jfName //This is where the error is pointing.
                        loadNames[i].lastName = jlName
                        loadNames[i].done = jDone
                        loadNames[i].frequent = jFrequent

                        println(loadNames.count)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the variables all seem to be getting the data from the JSON file and the value of 'i' in the 'for' loop when the error is happening is '0'.

I don't know why this is happening.

the array count is returning 6, which is the actual amount of objects in the JSON file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the loadNames array's `append` method to add each List object. Trying to access index i >= 0 in a zero length array is what is causing your error.